# Mochajs test function "It" never runs when called inside a Promise.then function

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, es6-promise, async.js

I have a weird issue with mochajs tests. I don't understand deep understanding of async and promise functions.

I have follow test in `mytest.js`

```
  describe(" store tests", () => {
  jsonfile.readFile(testDateFile).then(data => {
    describe("store is running", function() {
      it(`should show home page ${data}`, async function() {
        console.log("working");
      });
    });
  });
});
```

where `jsonfile.readFile` returns a Promise.

when I run the test with `./node_modules/.bin/mocha test/verify-urls.js`, it never gets into "it".
But when I add another describe like following

```
describe(" store tests", () => {
  describe("store is running", function() {
    it("should do nothing", () => {});
  });
  jsonfile.readFile(testDateFile).then(data => {
    describe("store is running", function() {
      it(`should show home page ${data}`, async function() {
        console.log("working");
      });
    });
  });
});
```

then `it(should show home page ${data}` is executed.

Any suggestion to understand the issue would be appreciated.

EDITED:
I figured it out. The problem is in `jsonfile.readFile(testDateFile)` .Since jsonfile.readFile is async and a different thread. Mocha test runner will in current thread and will not wait for returning Promise.
I simply moved the readFile method outside the tests and loaded before executing describe.

Comment: You need to await something within the it function.

Comment: `mocha` never supported async test definition (https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/1431). The second option seems be working by chance. You could move file reading to `before` hook instead.